# Select box - obtaining value of selected option by simple documen.getElementById('id').value

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I was supposed to retrieve a select box' value by something like this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("elementId");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

However, it seems that under some circumstances, the simple approach also works:

```
 var value = document.getElementById("elementId").value;
```

(Look: http://jsfiddle.net/uswnk9ng/)

Unfortunately, in my program this approach does not work always.

What does this working-or-not-working rely on?

Comment: Your jsFiddle works good for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: yes, my question is rather WHY it works because it is supposed to work not.

Comment: Why is it supposed not to work?

Comment: because this is supposed to be used instead: `var e = document.getElementById("elementId");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: Why "instead"? both works. Modern browsers read the `.value` directly from the select element.

Comment: yes, and that was new to me, because I learnt once to use the selectedIndex option